# 'Repeat the year' in English is 'redoubler une classe' in French. Would it be possible to say 'redouble the year' or 'redouble the course' in English?

Tags: verbs, word-usage

When I googled 'redouble the year' I was directed to French sites, and I noticed that it is  indeed used. Now, I want to have a confirmation from English native speakers. Can 'redouble' be used for 'repeat'?
I'd be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it can’t. The only use of *redouble* I can think of immediately is in *redouble your efforts*, with the sense of ‘work much harder’. If you have to repeat a course, you can say just that or, more simply, *do the course again*.

Comment: Also "redouble" is something in the card game Bridge.  Meaning you double a second time.

Comment: @GEdgar: Yes, there are several meanings, some of them quite specialized. 'Redouble your efforts' is the one that sprang to mind.

Comment: "Doubled and redoubled" appears in some common translations of the Passover Haggadah; e.g., ["Thus how much more so should we be grateful to the Omnipresent One for the doubled and redoubled goodness that He has bestowed upon us"](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/cgi-bin/calendar?holiday=pesach11101 "link"). This may just mean that the translators (or the Omnipresent One) love bridge, but I'd wager it's a literal translation.

Answer (score 2):

Although the dictionary definition of *redouble* is to double or to repeat, it is seldom used by native English speakers to mean this.

I strongly suspect that most English speakers would understand it to mean "to double something that *has already been doubled*. It is used in this exact sense in the game of Bridge.

The reasonably common idiom "He redoubled his efforts", can then be read as "Having already doubled his efforts, he doubled them again".

Again, this is not the dictionary definition, but it's my strong sense that that is how most people would understand it.

"Repeat the year" is what English speakers would say. There is no reason to look for an alternative phrase.

Comment: I wanted to know whether 'redouble' can ever be used in the context I've given. You are telling me it is 'seldom' used in that sense. So I deduce that it can be used though I will never use it to mean to repeat the year. Sounds awkward to my ear. Thank you Slim for your answer.

Comment: Yes, I said "seldom" because if I said "never" then one use would make me wrong. I'll add that the people who *do* use it are likely to be very confident native speakers. There is no reason for an ESL speaker to use the word redouble.